# Cmd+~ Not working in Xcode

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

The command + tilde keyboard shortcut has stopped working for me.  I simply get the system beep noise and nothing happens.  I checked to see if any of my keyboard shortcuts were modified in system `system preferences->keyboard->shortcuts` but i made sure that the defaults were restored.  Are there any other known reasons this shortcut may be disabled?  I've googled this for quite some time and can find no answers.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is a universal hint for latest macOS versions: try to reboot your Mac.

But I hope you've already fixed it.